# talk returns error when trying to connect to user at other machine

Tags: messaging

If I try to `talk` to a user on a machine on the local network, I get:

```
~ % talk toothrot@othermachine
[Service connection established.]
Error on write to talk daemon: Invalid argument
```

I'm running Arch.

`talk` works fine between users on the same machine. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Have you figured it out? I have the exact same issue …

Comment: @k.stm, no I gave up; let me know if you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Does the other machine have `talkd` running? It is typically a `(x)inetd` service.

Since the `talk` command is typically `setgid tty` so that it can access other users' terminal sessions, it can do the job locally on its own. For incoming talk requests from other hosts, you'll need a trusted local piece of software that can receive the talk request and pass it to the user's session - or reject it, if the user in question has `mesg n` set.

Allowing direct network access to users' sessions would be an open invitation for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Has the other user run:

```
mesg y
```

If not, this may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes, that's not it.